# Create 21 V power source from multiple 5 V sources

Tags: power-supply, voltage, batteries

Can I create a 21 V power source out of multiple 5 V sources?

Set the scene:

I have a mini projector, it runs off a 21 V power source. I have several 5 V power packs that I use for charging iPhones etc.

Would it be possible to create a circuit which takes in multiple power packs via USB and then outputs 21 V to power the projector?

Comment: Possible? yes, should you do it? no. These packs are designed to drive a single load, and not work together with other packs. You should get a proper power pack/adapter for your product.

Comment: Think it this way: Each of the power supplies try to keep 5VDC between its own output poles. You connect (through your projector, but connect anyway) several other power supplies which try to change that 5VDC to something which has more volts and reversed polarity. Someone wins, but difficult to predict who it might be. If you are lucky nothing smokes, but do not rely on it. My advice. Do not test it! Do as said already - get a proper power supply for the projector.

Answer (score 3):

Not such a good idea. It will be difficult to combine the sources in such a way that they each contributes according to their abilities and still supply the needs of the device being powered. Remember too that the current will be more than 4x higher at the 5V level than at the 21V level (plus more on top for the inevitable losses).

If you can find a USB power bank or supply with PD you can get a device such as one using the WCH CH224K chip or similar that will request 20V and you can likely use that for battery power or mains power. It's not hard to find power banks that will supply 66W, or more than 3A at 20V. Of course lower average power means more battery life per charge.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few power controllers that are designed to "combine" sources that are not designed to be paralleled, but they are not going to be usable by a hobbyist.

The usual method of paralleling DC sources is to provide each supply with a method of sensing current and a common communication line to enable the supplies to adjust their currents so that each supply is providing the same percentage of their own maximum power. Your supplies will not have that.

If there is one supply that can supply more power (watts) than the projector requires, then you could use a DC-DC converter to step it up to 21V but even that is probably going to be more expensive than buying a new supply.